# re-prompt input from the user using the same variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to recall the `continue_or_exit` variable in the `else:` of the following code?:

```
continue_or_exit = input('Would you like to "continue" or "exit"? ')
if continue_or_exit == 'continue':
   task3(word_lines, clueslistl, clueslists, clues)
elif continue_or_exit == 'exit':         
    quit()
else:
```

If not, is there another way of doing this, preferably without the need of a function?

Comment: By "recall", do you mean "ask the user again"?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use a function?

Comment: Yes, by 'recall' I do mean 'ask the user again'.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
while True:
    continue_or_exit = input('Would you like to "continue" or "exit"? ')
    if continue_or_exit == 'continue':
       task3(word_lines, clueslistl, clueslists, clues)
    elif continue_or_exit == 'exit':         
        quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop instead of if statements:

```
while True:
    continue_or_exit = input('Would you like to "continue" or "exit"? ')
    if continue_or_exit == 'continue':
       task3(word_lines, clueslistl, clueslists, clues)
    elif continue_or_exit == 'exit':         
        break
    else:
        print("Input not recognized, please try again.\n")
quit()
```

This should keep looping through and asking for input until the user chooses exit, although this is untested.